# absolute position in animated text messing up layout

Tags: javascript, css, animation, position

I have a div that is animating text. I seem to have to have it set to "absolute" or the animation isn't smooth, BUT, because it's absolute, the rest of the site is ignoring the box, even though I have it wrapped in another div that is relative.

Been pulling my hair out for days, would deeply appreciate assistance!

HTML:

```
<div id="cbp-qtrotator" class="cbp-qtrotator">

<div class="cbp-qtcontent current"><blockquote>
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 2em; text-align: center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at augue lectus.</p></blockquote></div>
      
<div class="cbp-qtcontent"><blockquote>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at augue lectus.</p></blockquote></div>
      
<div class="cbp-qtcontent"> <blockquote>
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at augue lectus.</p></blockquote></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cbp-qtrotator {
position: relative;
width: 90%;
max-width: 1225px;
max-height:600px;
margin: 75px auto 25px;
z-index:90;
}

.cbp-qtcontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none
}

.cbp-qtrotator .cbp-qtcontent.current {
  display: block
}

.cbp-qtrotator blockquote {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0
}

.cbp-qtrotator blockquote p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0.4em 0 1em
}

blockquote {border-left: none;}
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var divs = $('.cbp-qtcontent');
      
function fade() {
var current = $('.current');
var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
        
if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
nextIndex = 0;
}
        
var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);
        
next.stop().fadeIn(1500, function() {
$(this).addClass('current');
});
        
current.stop().fadeOut(1500, function() {
$(this).removeClass('current');
_startProgress()

setTimeout(fade, 5000);
});
}

function _startProgress(){
$(".cbp-qtprogress").removeAttr('style');
$(".cbp-qtprogress").animate({
 width:"800px",
} , 5000);
}
        
_startProgress()
setTimeout(fade, 5000);
});
</script>
```

The "cbp-qtcontent" absolute is causing the issue of the rest of the site not appearing under this animated text, but over it. If I change or remove it, the next line appears under the top, then the top vanishes, then the second line moves up. The site moves with it, but obviously that is not the smooth changing of text I am going for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your existing code to display anything for me without changes to the CSS.  I put your code into a fiddle and replaced all the CSS with the following. Only the first 2 lines are important, the others are just to help visualize the boxes.

```
.cbp-qtrotator{position:relative;margin-top:150px;border:1px solid black;background:yellow;height:100px}
.cbp-qtcontent blockquote{position:absolute;background:red;}
.cbp-qtcontent:nth-child(2) blockquote{background:green;}
.cbp-qtcontent:nth-child(3) blockquote{background:blue;}
```

Your relative container would need to set its height. Either fix the height to something large enough that any of your blockquote content will fit, or you'll have to use javascript to adjust it depending on which blockquote is display.  Fixed heights are probably a better idea visually as it prevents other elements/content on the page from moving around which in my opinion would be bad UI design.

Comment: Yes, tried the code, you need to set a min-height or height on .cbp-qtrotator

Comment: You're right, fixed height worked. What java would I use to control adjusting it based on the display because once it goes on different devices, as some of the text is much longer in that animated box, I don't really have a set size...

Comment: You mean javascript (java is different). As you begin to fade in the next element, get it's height and set the parent container to the same height.

Comment: How do I "get its height"? Do I set for each in the div HTML code? I posted only an example here, but there's 30 or so fading texts, so would have to be on each, or at least on the longer text ones. Thank you!

Comment: Phaelax z, I did not get any of the child colours when I used your code above. I also don't get how to use javascript to get the height to set the height per quote I am using. I am just someone that does some coding to make sites for other hobbies. Helping out a friend here. Appreciate more details. Thanks!!